# Left and right cosets of $H = \{e,(12)\}$ in $S_3$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

> Find the left cosets and the right cosets of the subgroup
>   $H=\{e,(12)\}$ of $S_3$. Verify that they are not identical. Can $H$
>   be a normal subgroup of $S_3$?

The elements of $S_3$ are basically $\{e, \alpha, \alpha ^2, \beta, \alpha\beta, \alpha^2\beta\}$, where

$$\alpha = \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 2 & 3 \\ 2 & 3 & 1 \end{bmatrix}$$

and $$\beta = \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 2 & 3 \\ 1 & 3 & 2 \end{bmatrix}$$

It is given that $H=\{e,\alpha\beta\}$

And we know for a fact that $\beta \alpha = \alpha^2\beta$

**Left Cosets of $H$:**

$\alpha H = \{\alpha, \alpha^2\beta\}$

$\alpha^2 H = \{\alpha^2,\alpha^3\beta\} = \{\alpha^2,\beta\}$

$\beta H = \{\beta,\beta\alpha\beta\} = \{\beta,\alpha^2\}$

$\alpha^2\beta H = \{\alpha^2\beta,\alpha\}$

Thus, we effectively have **three different left cosets**: $\{\alpha, \alpha^2\beta\},\{\alpha^2,\beta\},\{\alpha\beta, e\}$.

Similarly, we find out the **effective right cosets** to be:

$\{\alpha,\beta\},\{\alpha^2,\beta\alpha\}$ and $\{\alpha^2\beta,\alpha^2\}$

It is clear that the set of left cosets and the set of right cosets is non-overlapping and hence the required proof is completed. Also, surely $H$ **cannot be a normal subgroup** of $S_3$ since none of the left and right cosets match.

However, this was quite a lengthy method (i.e. finding all the left and right cosets of $H$ separately). Is there any shorter and more elegant method to approach the problem (at least the verification portion)?

Comment: Your right cosets are wrong, two of them are the same and you are missing the subgroup itself. (I have no idea what an "effective coset" means.)

Answer (score 1):

There are three equivalent definitions for normal subgroups:

> Let $G$ be a group and $H$ a subgroup of $G$. Then $H$ is normal in $G$ if any of the three equivalent conditions hold:
>
> - $Hg = gH$ for every $g \in G$;
> - $g^{-1}Hg = H$ for every $g \in G$;
> - $g^{-1}hg \in H$ for every $h \in H$ and $g \in G$.

So if you can find any $g \in G$ such that $g^{-1}hg \notin H$ for some $h \in H$, then $H$ is not normal in $G$.

In your example, let $g = (1 \quad 2 \quad 3)$ and $h = (1 \quad 2)$, so that (multiplying left-to-right) we have
$$
g^{-1}hg = (1 \quad 3 \quad 2)(1 \quad 2)(1 \quad 2 \quad 3) = (2 \quad 3) \notin H.
$$
Hence $H$ is not normal in $G$. This is much faster!